# LineChart add whitespace to top

Tags: mpandroidchart

I'm trying to add whitespace to the top of my chart so I can fit my title etc. into the top without overlapping with the grids, is there a simple way to do this? If I increase the height then the x/y axis scales with it, can I make them smaller?

Answer (score 0):

LineChart.chart.setExtraTopOffset()

That method took way too long to find.